# Restricting linespread to an environment

Tags: line-spacing

`\linespread` doesn't seem to be taken in consideration when set in an environment. How can I reduce the space between lines in a specific environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside your environment you can use one of the commands `\singlespacing`, `\onehalfspacing` or `\doublespacing`, or the `spacing` environment from the `setspace` package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand\TestText{test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test }
\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
  {\begin{spacing}{#1}}
  {\end{spacing}}

\begin{document}

\TestText
\begin{myenv}{1.6}
\TestText
\end{myenv}
\begin{myenv}{0.6}
\TestText
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just a small comment: When you use \singlespacing you also need to have the spacing package installed.

Comment: @PanchoPino: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I moved your comment here. Note that you shouldn't write answer posts to comment on answers. Note that you can't [comment everywhere until getting 50rep](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PanchoPino: You must be referring to the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace), since there is no `spacing` package.

Comment: Is there also a simple way to define custom factors - not only 0.5 steps?

Comment: @Eric: I am not sure I understand your question. Could you explain in more detail, please?

Comment: Sure! When using package setspace, one may use \singlespacing, \onehalfspacing, \doublespacing and so on. I.e. using linespread factor 1.0, 1.5 or 2.0. But is it also possible to use factors that are different, e.g. linespacing 1.25?

Comment: How can I do this when I want to change the spacing in the title? I'm writing the title with a simple `\title{}`