# Why do I get a big black line in my document? (Tikzpicture)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I do not understand why, but somehow I get a big black line in my pdf, why?

head:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\parindent=0pt
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\title{Matematisk modellering}
\author{}
\date{February 2016}
\begin{document}
```

code:

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
scale=3,
>=stealth,
point/.style = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = 1pt},
dot/.style   = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = .2pt},
]
%
% the circle
\draw (0,0) circle (2.12cm);
%
% triangle nodes: just points on the circle
\node (n0) at (0,0) [point, label = below:$S$] {};
\node (n1) at (-1.5,1.5) [point, label = below:$R_{1}$] {};
\node (n2) at (-3,0) [point, label = {below left:$R_{2}$}] {};
\node (n3) at (-2.12,0) [point, label = {below left:$q$}] {};
%
% triangle edges: connect the vertices, and leave a node at the midpoint
\draw[-] (n0) -- node (a) [label = {below left:$\gamma$}] {} (n1);
\draw[-] (n0) -- node (a) [label = {below right:$\gamma$}] {} (n2);
\draw[-] (n2) -- node (a) [label = {below :$vt_{1,2}$}] {} (n3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure*}
```

[image: My Circle]

Comment: Try looking at the log: I bet you'll find "Overfull \hbox" someplace. I'm pretty sure that is what is called _overfull rule_, indicating you have a line that is out of the page margin. To get that away, either scale the picture, or give your class the `final` option.

Comment: You were correct.

Comment: Perfect. Would you accept the answer I posted so I can flag the other thing as a duplicate of this one?

Comment: Is there anything more I need to do, than just saying that I accept it?

Comment: Click the checkmark on its left. That's what we mean here by "accept an answer".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I should point out two things:

- Package `mcode` is not available on my computer, which means it either isn't in TeXLive or is in the form of an `.ins` to be typeset to get a `.sty` from it, as `rmathbr` is on CTAN; either way, it is useless, so a good MWE should ideally *not* include it;
- Secondly, I compiled the following code:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{verbatim}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  %\usepackage[]{mcode}
  \usepackage[swedish]{babel}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{subfig}

  \parindent=0pt
  \setlength{\parskip}{1em}

  \title{Matematisk modellering}
  \author{}
  \date{February 2016}
  \begin{document}

  \begin{figure*}[t!]\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  [
  scale=3,
  >=stealth,
  point/.style = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = 1pt},
  dot/.style   = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = .2pt},
  ]
  %
  % the circle
  \draw (0,0) circle (2.12cm);
  %
  % triangle nodes: just points on the circle
  \node (n0) at (0,0) [point, label = below:$S$] {};
  \node (n1) at (-1.5,1.5) [point, label = below:$R_{1}$] {};
  \node (n2) at (-3,0) [point, label = {below left:$R_{2}$}] {};
  \node (n3) at (-2.12,0) [point, label = {below left:$q$}] {};
  %
  % triangle edges: connect the vertices, and leave a node at the midpoint
  \draw[-] (n0) -- node (a) [label = {below left:$\gamma$}] {} (n1);
  \draw[-] (n0) -- node (a) [label = {below right:$\gamma$}] {} (n2);
  \draw[-] (n2) -- node (a) [label = {below :$vt_{1,2}$}] {} (n3);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{figure*}

  \end{document}
  ```

  to get *no* overfull rule:

  [image]

  So either you have some out-of-date package, or the code you gave does *not* reproduce your problem.

Assuming you have up-to-date packages, that black line is showing you what the following message tells you:

```
Overfull \hbox (13.73792pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 45--46
```

that is, *you have a line that's getting out of the page margin*, in this case, a huge picture. So you can either:

- Add the `final` option to `article`, i.e. `\documentclass[final]{article}`;
- Change `margin=3cm` to e.g. `margin=2cm`, which removes the overfull;
- Change `scale=3` to e.g. `scale=2`;
- Try some `\parbox` or `minipage` trickery, though I'm not sure that can widen the margin and remove the overfull; after all, I hardly ever use `minipage`, and only use `\parbox` via [a macro built for a very specific purpose](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287064/auto-linebreaking-in-underset).

For the record, a very similar question was asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295074/latex-puts-a-black-edge-on-my-image), and assuming you googled first, you probably didn't find it because of the "edge". Well now we have a nice duplicate target for that question: this one. Flagging soon.

It *is* strange that you got that. Were you using `draft` option? Because it should not be default…

**Additional remarks**

Since you are using LaTeX, you may well want to use the `center` environment rather than the plain-TeX `\centering` macro. I do not know if there are any big "upsides" to this choice, but it is generally considered good practice to use LaTeX where you can, and resort to TeX when writing macros where LaTeX is not convenient, unless I'm much mistaken. So I suggest you remove `\centering` and wrap the `figure` inside `\begin{center}…\end{center}`.

This MWE needs neither `inputenc`, nor `verbatim`, nor `mathtools`, nor `graphicx`, nor `mcode`, nor `babel`, so to make it really minimal, you should have removed those packages. They only clutter the code and may make others think one of those is the problem, when the problem is just an overfull box. And I think `geometry` is also not needed.

In general, before posting, you should check your code reproduces your problem. In this case, it didn't. If the code must be an example of the problem, and it doesn't show the problem, then it's not a good example, right :)?

**Update**

Turns out I was partly wrong in the part about `center`. Quoting @barbarabeeton's comment:

> the `center` environment adds extra space above and below; `\centering` does not.  sometimes the environment results in too much space, and in that situation, `\centering` is not only appropriate, but recommended.

Comment: Im writing in ShareLatex. I cuted this figure out from a BIG document. You are right I should have tried to run just the code presented. But somehow, just following your first comment above, solved the whole thing.

Comment: Perhaps ShareLatex fiddles with class options, making `draft` default and `final` the one to be specified. Bizarre behaviour if you ask me, but if you weren't passing `draft` the black line should not have appeared...

Comment: the `center` environment adds extra space above and below; `\centering` does not.  sometimes the environment results in too much space, and in that situation, `\centering` is not only appropriate, but recommended.