# Changing linespread in newenvironment

Tags: environments, fontsize, line-spacing

I'm trying to construct a `figurenotes` environment that should have `\footnotesize` and a different `\linespread` but can't seem to adjust the latter. My MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newenvironment{figurenotes}{\linespread{2}\par\vspace{1em}\footnotesize\selectfont\emph{Notes.}}{}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[tb]
    \caption{Pagodas}
    \label{fig:pagodas}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pagodas}
    \begin{figurenotes}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \end{figurenotes}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Results: linespread unaffected]

Comment: I don't see what you're missing: you asked for `\linespread{2}` and `footnotesize`. At first glance it seems to be the case. What's wriong with the result?

Comment: The linespread command is ignored. The result is identical without it.

Comment: But I realize that this question might already be answered here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24562/restricting-linespread-to-an-environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting to add `\par` in the `\end` part of the environment.

With your code, the `\par` is executed at `\end{figure}`, when the `\linespread{2}` setting has been forgotten because `figurenotes` has alredy ended. What you get is the baseline skip for `\normalsize`.

```latex
\newenvironment{figurenotes}
  {\par\addvspace{1em}%
   \linespread{2}\footnotesize
   \emph{Notes.} \ignorespaces
  }
  {\par}% <-------  IMPORTANT
```

Note a few changes: `\linespread{2}` should only affect the table notes, so it should be issued after the initial `\par`. There's no need of `\selectfont`, because `\footnotesize` does it.

The space after `\emph{Notes.}` should be explicitly in the definition, otherwise input such as

```
\begin{figurenotes}This is a figure\end{figurenotes}
```

would have no space. With `\ignorespaces` we remove the possible spurious space that may come from the endline after `\begin{figurenotes}`.

[image]